# After submitting a login form, URL remains on the action php

Tags: php, mysql, forms, authentication

Hi there I am currently working on a user login where there can be 2 different situations when a person submits the form.

What I am trying to accomplish is that if someone logs in, 
they would either be redirected to the user page or the admin page depending on what table their username is located.

My problem is, after submitting the form, the browser shows a blank page with no errors, with the URL being the php action of the form.

Here is my html file

```
<?php
//Start session
//error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE;
ini_set( 'error_reporting', E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE);
session_start();

//Unset the variables stored in session
unset($_SESSION['SESS_MEMBER_ID']);
unset($_SESSION['SESS_USERNAME']);
unset($_SESSION['SESS_PASSWORD']);
?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" title="" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/animate.css" title="" />
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,600,700,300' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.js">            </script>
<script src="js/mouseEvents.js"></script>
<title>Grey Avenue Item Inventory Login</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="container">

<div id="mainform" >
    <div id="formcontainer" class="animated fadeInDown">
        <div id="formheader">
        <div class="logocont">
            <a href="#"><span class="logoImg"></span></a>
            <h2 class="textheader">Inventory System Log-In</h2>
        </div>

        </div>
    <form action="login.php" method="post" id="loginform">

    <div class="inputbox">  <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username" maxlength="12"/></div>
    <div class="inputbox"> <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password"  maxlength="12"/></div>
    </form>
    <div id="loginbutton">
            <button type="submit" form="loginform" class="loginbutton" value="Log In">
            <span class="loginbut_text">Log In</span>
            </button>
            <button class="regbutton" value="Register">
            <span class="loginbut_text">Register</span>
            </button>
        </div>  

        <div id="errormsg">
<?php
if( isset($_SESSION['ERRMSG_ARR']) && is_array($_SESSION['ERRMSG_ARR']) &&     count($_SESSION['ERRMSG_ARR']) >0 ) {
echo '<ul class="err">';
foreach($_SESSION['ERRMSG_ARR'] as $msg) {
echo '<li>',$msg,'</li>';
}
echo '</ul>';
unset($_SESSION['ERRMSG_ARR']);
}
?>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>



</body>
</html>
```

And my login.php file

```
<?php

session_start();

require("connect.php");
require("lib/password.php");

//Array to store validation errors
$errmsg_arr = array();

//Validation error flag
$errflag = false;


$username = $_POST["username"];
$password = $_POST["password"];

//Input Validations
if($username == "") {
    $errmsg_arr[] = "*Username missing";
    $errflag = true;
}
if($password == "") {
    $errmsg_arr[] = "*Password missing";
    $errflag = true;
}

//If there are input validations, redirect back to the login form
if($errflag) {
    $_SESSION["ERRMSG_ARR"] = $errmsg_arr;
    session_write_close();
    header("location: index.php");
    die();
}

if ($sql = $conn->prepare("SELECT id, username, password, firstName, lastName FROM users WHERE username = ?")){

    $sql->bind_param("s", $username) ;
    $sql->execute();
    $sql->store_result();
    $result = $sql->num_rows;
    $sql->bind_result($id, $username, $passwordhash, $firstName, $lastName);
    $sql->fetch();

    if ($result > 0){
        if(password_verify($password, $passwordhash)){
            session_regenerate_id();
            $_SESSION["SESS_MEMBER_ID"] = $id;
            $_SESSION["SESS_USERNAME"] = $username;
            $_SESSION["SESS_PASSWORD"] = $password;
            $_SESSION["SESS_FIRSTNAME"] = $firstName;
            $_SESSION["SESS_LASTNAME"] = $lastName;

            session_write_close();

            header("location: inventory.php");
            die();  
        }
        else {
            //Login failed
            $errmsg_arr[] = "Username and Password do not match";
            $errflag = true;
            if($errflag) {
                $_SESSION["ERRMSG_ARR"] = $errmsg_arr;
                session_write_close();
                header("location:index.php");
                die();
            }
        }
    }
}
else {
    if($sql = $conn->prepare("SELECT id, username, password, firstName, lastName     FROM admin WHERE username=?")){
        $sql->bind_param("s", $username);
        $sql->execute();
        $sql->store_result();
        $result = $sql->num_rows;

        $sql->bind_result($id, $username, $passwordhash, $firstName, $lastName);
        $sql->fetch();

        if($result > 0){
            if(password_verify($password, $passwordhash)){
                session_regenerate_id();
                $_SESSION["SESS_MEMBER_ID"] = $id;
                $_SESSION["SESS_USERNAME"] = $username;
                $_SESSION["SESS_PASSWORD"] = $password;
                $_SESSION["SESS_FIRSTNAME"] = $firstName;
                $_SESSION["SESS_LASTNAME"] = $lastName;

                session_write_close();

                header("location:  http://www.greyavenue.ph/shoplogin/inventoryadmin.php");
                die();  
            }
            else {
                //Login failed
                $errmsg_arr[] = "Username and Password do not match";
                $errflag = true;
                if($errflag) {
                    $_SESSION["ERRMSG_ARR"] = $errmsg_arr;
                    session_write_close();
                    header("location: index.php");
                    die();
                }
            }
        }
        else{
            //Login failed
            $errmsg_arr[] = "Username and Password not found";
            $errflag = true;
            if($errflag) {
                $_SESSION["ERRMSG_ARR"] = $errmsg_arr;
                session_write_close();
                header("location: http://www.greyavenue.ph/shoplogin/index.php");
                die();
            }
        }
    }
}
?>
```

I am confused because the login seems to function and redirect the browser to the pages when I am not hashing the password before, but now after changing the code with the hash function the URL remains at this php file.

Really appreciate the effort in taking the time to read and answer my question in advance! Thanks!

Comment: place your html code also

Comment: Any error messages being reported? Error reporting is on?

Comment: There are no errors being reported. Edited it with the html file.

Comment: Use `exit()`, instead of `die()`. Add `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` to the the top of login.php. Now what happens (add it to your question).

Comment: As far as I'm aware, location headers are always in this format:  `Location: http://www.example.com/url.php`  Note the capital L and single space after the colon.

Comment: I added 
    error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);
the top of login.php and also changed the location headers to
    Location: http://www.example.com/url.php 

still there is no error code showing and the url remains on login.php thanks for your replies appreciate them!

Comment: Place `echo`s throughout your code to see where the program is ending up. You have a case where: if the first $conn->prepare return true but the query returns 0 rows, you don't do anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a logical error:

your code, stripped to the beef:

```
if ($sql = $conn->prepare("SELECT id, username, password, firstName, lastName FROM users WHERE username = ?")){

    // retrieve result

    if ($result > 0){
        // check result
    }
}
else {
    // select from admin
}
```

In the case you have a user/pwd tupel which doesn't fit, the `$result` is 0.
In this particular cse, none of the redirect branches will be hit and the page just shows as empty.

you need to change similar to the following:

```
if ($sql = $conn->prepare("SELECT id, username, password, firstName, lastName FROM users WHERE username = ?")){
  // handle sql error
}
// retrieve result
if ($result > 0){
        // check result, either logged in or error
}

// no result in users, check admin:
if ($sql = $conn->prepare("SELECT id, username, password, firstName, lastName FROM admin WHERE username = ?")){
  // handle sql error
}
// retrieve result
if ($result > 0){
        // check result, either logged in or error
}
```

Comment: This was the perfect answer to my problem. I had no clue what was happening since there was no error code showing. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

What seems to be happening is that error reporting is off (you set it on in your "html" file but not in login.php) and at the same time there is an issue inside your password_verify() function.

You should post that function as well so that we can take a look.

**UPDATE**
Also if you are using as it seems a password_verify that is not the built in one, and your PHP is 5.5 or greater you may be trying to define a function with a reserved name (password_verify) and thus getting a fatal error, which you can't see, as apparently errors are not displayed in your server.

Comment: I doubt the error is with [`password_verify()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) as it's a built in function and not one of the OP's functions.

Comment: as far as i can tell he is requiring lib/password.php 
I think that he is using another password_verify() function and not the built in one. Possibly he is not in PHP 5.5 branch but on an earlier one without that function. Edited to reflect possible issues if he is running in newer php and trying to re define password verify...

Comment: Hi there, thank you for your feedback. the webserver I am using is below php 5.5 so I imported a password_compat lib for the`password_hash()` function I also added the error reporting code on top of login.php but still no error code is showing.

Comment: Ok then add the following right after $errflag = false;


echo nl2br(print_r($_POST));
echo 'Up to this point it works<br>';
exit;


You should see a dump of $_POST and the script will echo and stop.
Start moving down after the next php line,  the last two lines (the echo and the exit) and try it out. that way you will find where the script has the issue.

Answer (score 0):

make this changes in your html code

```
        <form action="login.php" method="post" id="loginform">
        <div class="inputbox">  <input type="text" name="username"   placeholder="Username" maxlength="12"/></div>
       <div class="inputbox"> <input type="password" name="password"   placeholder="Password"  maxlength="12"/></div>
        <div id="loginbutton">
        <button type="submit" form="loginform" class="loginbutton" value="Log In">
        <span class="loginbut_text">Log In</span>
        </button>
        <button class="regbutton" value="Register">
        <span class="loginbut_text">Register</span>
        </button>
       </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi guys I have solved my problem which was pretty simple and I am very sorry if I have troubled you.

I forgot to put the second else query statement inside the first one where it checks the number of rows available.

Many thanks for your insights and feedbacks!